# Pass click action using array and v-for (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to pass through a v-for the text and the @click action of each li. For the text I know how to do it...but for the click action?`enter code here`

Each item of the array menuOptions (which is in the 'data' part of my Vue component) is structured like this :

```
{name: "firstOption",action: "console.log('first option called')"}
```

The first parameter is the name of the option, the

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="option in menuOptions" @click="option.action">{{option.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Do you have some ideas? (I guess that's maybe a pure JS question, but maybe there are possibilities to do it Vue too?)

Comment: `@click="option.action"` It doesn't work?

Comment: `@click="option.action"` should just work. Anyway post `menuOptions`.

Comment: I updated my first post. Doing "option.action" doesn't work. When clicking, nothing hapens. It's probably my way to defined "action...please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a function expression to the `action` property, instead of a "stringified" function.

```
{
  name: 'firstOption',
  action: function() {console.log('first option called'}
}
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    menuOptions: [{
      action: function() {
        console.log('foo')
      },
      name: 'foo'
    }, {
      action: function() {
        console.log('bar')
      },
      name: 'bar'
    }],
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <div id='app'>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="option in menuOptions" @click="option.action">{{option.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```